# handle asynchronous behavior firebase in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, firebase, promise

I'm trying put the authentication of my **firebase** in a service. But I stumbled on some problems with program flow. The response from firebase is slower and the code needs to wait for it to complete.

I tried to create a **promise**, but it doesnt work properly.
Here is my code:

//controller.js

```
articleControllers.controller('AuthController', 
    ['$scope', '$firebaseObject', 'AuthenticationService', 
    function($scope, $firebaseObject, AuthenticationService){


        $scope.login = function() {    
             AuthenticationService.login($scope.loginForm)
            .then(function(result) {
                if(result.error) {
                    $scope.message= result.error.message;
                }
                else {
                    console.log("user");
                }
            });
        };  
    }
 ]);
```

services.js

```
myApp.factory('AuthenticationService',
function($firebase, $firebaseAuth, $routeParams, FIREBASE_URL) {

    var auth = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);

    var myReturnObject = {

        //user login
        login: function(user) {
            return auth.authWithPassword({
                email: user.loginEmail,
                password: user.loginPassword
            },
            function(error, authData) {
                console.log("hit after .then");
                return {
                    error: error,
                    authData: authData
                }
            });
         }

    };

    return myReturnObject;
});
```

I already used a promise once in my code for a $http get request. But for firebase it doesnt seem to work. I get the **error: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined in controller.js**.
Anyone an idea how I can let angular wait for the service?

Comment: Do you want that semi colon before the `.then`?

Comment: No, its a typo while simplifying my code. I edit it.

Comment: firebase function authWithPassword does not return promise, it is a callback style. you need to create promise in your code.

Comment: in service.js or controller.js? Could you provide a short example? It would be much appreciated. I already tried a 100 things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remember to inject `$q`.

```
myApp.factory('AuthenticationService',
function($q, $firebase, $firebaseAuth, $routeParams, FIREBASE_URL) {

    var auth = new Firebase(FIREBASE_URL);

    var myReturnObject = {

        //user login
        login: function(user) {
          return $q(function(resolve, reject) {
            auth.authWithPassword({
                email: user.loginEmail,
                password: user.loginPassword
            }, function authCallback(error, authData) {
              if (error) {
                return reject(error);
              }
              resolve(authData);

            });
          });

         }

    };

    return myReturnObject;
});
```